# Dana in Thailand or Sri Lanka

Tags: dana

I'm sorry it may be a little off topic, does anyone here know anywhere in Thailand or Sri Lanka where Dana is being carried out? Preferably central area, more accessible.
Thanks!

Comment: See also [Interacting with monks in Thailand](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3429/254) and note that both answers mention some extra rules for women.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.Those standard ones like no direct contact when offering food are pretty common.But still, I saw some of them just scoop and put it into the Monk's alm. Aren't they suppose to put them on a piece of clothe or something?

Comment: Into the monk's "bowl" or "alms bowl", do you mean? I don't know. [Bakmoon's answer](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3449/254) said the monks will lay out a cloth (I guess instead of accepting it directly into their hand) if you are offering something other than food (with food being put directly into the bowl, for example as shown in Sankha's video recording below).

Comment: Sorry,I meant alms bowl.Yeah,exactly.Usually the monk will lay out a cloth.Yes,watched. =)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are a layman looking for free food, come to Sri Lanka during the Vesak or Poson full moon poya days. You will find many free food outlets. Usually you can get rice & curry, noodles, sandwiches, ice cream, various beverages etc.

If you are a monk, you can go on alms round on any day. You will be offered food in most cities.

If you're actually looking to do the dana offering to monks, just go to any temple and make your wishes known to the head monk: they will give you a date. Alternately, you can go near monasteries like Meethirigala and try to catch a monk who's going on alms round. Here's a recording I did in January: [Pindapathe on Election Day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCudZFi-rOQ)

Comment: Hi Sankha, thanks for your response. I'm actually looking to do the dana offering to Monks. =)

Comment: Just go to any temple and make your wishes known to the head monk. They will give you a date. Alternately, you can go near monasteries like meethirigala and try to catch a monk who's going on alms round. Here's a recording I did in January: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCudZFi-rOQ

Comment: Just checked out Meetirigala Nissarana Vanaya, will join for a retreat if time permits. Anyway, is tourist allow to visit the monastery?

Comment: Tourists or foreigners who wants to meditate? Also what type of meditation you are looking for?

Comment: Just tourist dropping by to visit the monastery, is it appropriate?

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't make noise or try to talk with meditators or visit their kutis.